# Find minimum number of coins with Largest value coins?

Tags: optimization, algorithms, computer-science, contest-math, dynamic-programming

There is a greedy algorithm for coin change problem : using most valuable coin as possible. How We can find a quick method to see which of following sets of coin values this algoithms cannot find optimal solutions (i.e the minimum number of coins). We assume that we have infinitely many coins of each type.

Examples: $\{1, 4, 7\}$, $\{1, 2, 5\}$, $\{1, 7, 10\}$, $\{1, 5, 10\}$

> Why just the third set is not optimal and other sets is optimal?

I see one paper on [Link](http://arxiv.org/PS_cache/arxiv/pdf/0809/0809.0400v1.pdf) but not familiar with me.

Comment: cannot find optimal solutions for what?

Comment: @fleablood I correct it, this algorithm cannot find optimal solution for third set. why ?

Comment: Are you asking for the definition of "optimal"?  Or for general theorems?  In this case, the greedy algorithm is sub-optimal for the third group (eg. $14=7+7$ is better than $14=10+1+1+1+1$.  Is that what you were after?

Comment: @lulu exactly my problem is here. how you quickly find that this is not optimal? if I didn't mentioned the third set is not optimal, you find it? create a counterexample is not very easy?

Comment: It looks like Theorem 4 in the linked-to paper contains the answer.

Comment: it's very complex for me, is it possible show it by example? @BarryCipra

Comment: @user4249446, if we let $c_2=7$ and $c_3=10$ in Theorem 4, then $q=1$ and $r=3$ (i.e., $10=1\cdot7+3$), and we see that $0\lt3\lt7-1$, hence $\{1,7,10\}$ is "non-canonical," meaning the greedy algorithm is sub-optimal.

Comment: How we choose C2 or C3? is there any quick way?  post as an answer. @BarryCipra

Comment: @user4249446, I was showing why the third set in your question is not optimal.  If, on the other hand, you want to show why, for example, the fourth set *is* optimal, choose $c_2=5$ and $c_3=10$.  Theorem 4 **is** the quick way to tell if a set is optimal (i.e., "canonical").

Comment: would you please explain  with short tutorial? how this value taken? thanks @BarryCipra

Answer (score 1):

Theorem 4 in the OP's linked-to paper says that a set $\{1,c_2,c_3\}$ with $1\lt c_2\lt c_3$ is "non-canonical" (meaning the greedy algorithm is sub-optimal) if and only if $0\lt r\lt c_2-q$, where $c_3=qc_2+r$ with $0\le r\lt c_2$.

Thus $\{1,7,10\}$ is non-canonical because $q=1$ and $r=3$ (i.e., $10=1\cdot7+3$) and $0\lt3\lt7-1$.

On the other hand, $\{1,4,7\}$ *is* canonical because $7=1\cdot4+3$ implies $q=1$ and $r=3$ and the condition $0\lt r\lt c_2-q$ does *not* hold since $3$ is not less than $4-1$.

The other two sets can be handled similarly.  It's just a matter of working out the $q$ and $r$ for each set and checking that either $0=r$ or $r=c_2-q$.

Comment: Sorry Barry, would you please inspect other two sets? a litle confused :)

Comment: Barry I need help on set {1,2,5} which value should be assign to Q?

Comment: @user4249446, $q$ and $r$ are the *quotient* and *remainder*, respectively, when you divide the larger number $c_3$ by the smaller number $c_2$.  So how many times does $2$ go into $5$, and with what remainder?

Comment: for {1, 2, 5} we get 5=1.2+3 ? am I right?

Comment: @user4249446, when doing division, the remainder is always *smaller* than the number you're dividing by -- that's what Theorem 4 means when it says "with $0\le r\lt c_2$."  When you write $5=1\cdot2+3$, you are getting a "remainder" of $3$, which is *not* less than $2$.